# How to receive async function response from another function? using promises.

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

How to receive async function response from another function? using promises.

Here is an example, lets say i have two function, when one of them responsible to greet people and other responsible to send a request.  How to organize my code to be able to hold all the request logic inside askGoogle function?

```
function greetings(lang) {
 var response;
 if(lang == 'en')
   response "Hello";
 else 
   response = askGoogle(lang);

 return response
}

askGoogle = function(lang) {
  $.getJSON('http://somelinkhere').then(function(data) {///})

  return ...// something here..
}
```

Comment: You could use just a callback: `var askGoogle = function(lang, callback){ //... };`

Comment: @kmsdev It is possible but for this specific case. I need a generic solution

Comment: The use of callbacks are generic. It works for all you need. It's a code-logic question. But you want to use jQuery promise, so my comment is just an alternative way, but valid and generic. @MJVakili did it well with promise.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function greetings(lang) {
 var response;
 if(lang == 'en')
   response "Hello";
 else 
   response = askGoogle(lang);
response .then(function(){}) //for example
 return response
}

askGoogle = function(lang) {
   return $.getJSON('http://somelinkhere').then(function(data) {///})


}
```

Comment: Or maybe `$.when(greetings('strLang')).then(function(data){...});`